# constrained Delaunay Triangulation vs Ear-clipping

Tags: triangulation, delaunay

I'm not an expert in triangulation questions. So I decide to ask.  :) 
There is a simple Ear Clipping algoritm which has complexity O(n^2) 
And there is constrained Delaunay algoritm which has complexity O(n * log n)

So the question is. Is Delaunay algoritm faster than Ear Clipping? I ask, because I understand, that if n time is significantly bigger for Delaunay, it may be slower after all.

P.S. http://code.google.com/p/poly2tri/ - Delaunay,
http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/TriangulationByEarClipping.pdf - Ear clipping

P.P.S By the way, is the constrained Delaunay the fastest one?

Comment: O(n) does not tell you how fast it works, it tells you how fast the speed is slowing down for each next element. In under 100 vertices both could be equally fast, but Delaunay produces much more uniform triangles, which may be beneficial in long-run.

Comment: Why uniform triangles is a plus? And what about, lets say 1000 elements, I guess this is practical max for shape :)) I worry, because I see atan (arctangens) in Delaunay implementation. Which is extremly slow.

Comment: It largely depends on what for you are going to use the results. If you need to pick fastest - you need to profile in your environment with real-life data. Otherwise it's all theoretic.

Answer (score 0):

Sweepline Delaunay algoritm can be O(n*log(n)) not O(log(n)).

With small number of points an implementation with worst case O(n^2) can be faster than O(n*log(n)) implementation.

One reason can be that the O(n*log(n)) algorithm might have to use a hierarchical data structure. Constantly adding and removing points and balancing a tree can be costly and make the algorithm run slower.

Answer (score 0):

In real world settings you can observe linear running time for Delaunay triangulations. At least for C++ there are libraries that triangulate >1 mio points per second:

[www.cgal.org](http://www.cgal.org)

http://www.geom.at/fade2d/html/

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try to lift the points and project back the lower convex hull of the lifted points to the 2d plane. The result should give the delaunay triangulation :https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2400/brute-force-delaunay-triangulation-algorithm-complexity.